# Django redirect inside a function

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build forum. When processing urls there is a board id and a board name. The board name exists just for user readability meaning if someone enters the id correctly but the board name is wrong or has changed it will redirect them to the correct url. I created a function to manage this because there are multiple times I need to check if the board is right, not just this one url.

```
# urls.py
...
url(r'^boards/(?P<board_id>\d+)/(?P<board_name>[^/]+)/$', views.board, name='board'),
...

# views.py
def board(request, board_id, board_name):
    RedirectIfWrong(request, board_id, board_name)
    ...
    return render(request, 'forums/board.html', {'board': board})

def RedirectIfWrong(request, pk, name):
    board = Board.objects.all().get(pk=pk)
    if (board.name != name):
        return redirect(request.get_full_path().replace(name, board.name, 1))
```

However when I call redirect inside a function it does not work. I have also heard of using middleware to do this. How does that work and how do I make it only apply to urls involving a board?

Answer (score 2):

```
def board(request, board_id, board_name):
    bad = RedirectIfWrong(request, board_id, board_name)
    if bad:
      return bad
    ...
    return render(request, 'forums/board.html', {'board': board})
```

Comment: If I have to do this to every view I want it becomes a mess and is not useful at all. Can someone please tell me if there is a way to do this with middleware or decorators?

Comment: I was trying to fix the code you have already written. If you are going to apply this validation in many of your views , then you are better move this validation logic to a decorator which you can apply to all of your views that need the same validation.

Answer (score 1):

Add the return

```
def board(request, board_id, board_name):
    return RedirectIfWrong(request, board_id, board_name)
    # ^^^^
```

Comment: This allows me to return the redirect but also causes an error if it is right in the first place. The view forums.views.board didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Comment: In the function `RedirectIfWrong ` you need add else statement something like it `return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Page not found</h1>')`

Comment: I am confused. I need it to not return if it is correct so it can process the rest of the view. While reading I have found decorators and middleware. Are any of these appropriate to use in this situation?

Comment: try the gipsy logic: